# BOOT\FCD error, STOP : 0x0000007B error, a problem has been detected and Windows has been shut down

Tags: windows-xp, boot, system-restore, bsod

When I boot , then this error comes:

```
\BOOT\FCD
```

After that , I boot through a Windows XP installation CD , then it says this:

> A problem has been detected and Windows has been shut down to prevent damage to your computer
>
> STOP: 0x0000007B
>
> Run `CHKDSK /F` to check for hard drive corruption and then restart your computer

*Now, how to run this command when am not able to boot into Windows itself, so i how would i enter DOS by going to Start Menu -->Programs-->Accessories-->Command Prompt?*

My important data was in the E:\ which was not having any Windows. I don't want to lose it.

Comment: your question is ambiguous, we don't know what you mean by the italicized line...

Comment: I'm guessing @sqlchild is asking how to run `chkdsk /f` when the standard boot has the \BOOT\FCD error, and a CD boot has a STOP error.

Comment: @studiohack: yes, my problem is what @Gareth has mentioned

Answer (score 2):

You need to boot into the Windows XP install disk and select the checkdisk option from there.